# How to implement "where not" in laravel eloquent query builder

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What is the laravel equivalent eloquent query builder for this mysql sql snippet:

```
select * from `posts` left join `user_post_interactions` on `posts`.`id` = `user_post_interactions`.`post_id` where `posts`.`user_id` = 10 and not (`user_post_interactions`.`interaction_name` = 'hide' and `user_post_interactions`.`user_id` = 10)
```

What I am doing is:

```
$this->posts()->leftJoin('user_post_interactions', 'posts.id', '=', 'user_post_interactions.post_id')
            ->where(function($q) {
                $q->where('user_post_interactions.interaction_name', '<>', 'hide')
                    ->where('user_post_interactions.user_id', '<>', 10);
            });
```

But this is not producing the result I expected

Comment: use whereRaw  more details https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) which will only query posts which have an `interaction` where the `user_id` does not equal `10`:

```
$this->posts()->whereHas('interactions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('user_id', '!=', 10);
})->get();
```

Note this will require a `Interaction` model with a `interactions()` relationship on the `Post` model.

If you would like to include `interactions` with the query, add `->with('interactions')` to the query chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run:

```
$this->posts()->with(['interaction' => function($query){
            return $query->where("interaction_name","!=",'hide')
                ->where("user_id","!=",10);
        }]);
```

If you wants to filter having interaction

```
$this->posts()->whereHas('interaction', function($query){
            return $query->where("interaction_name","!=",'hide')
                ->where("user_id","!=",10);
        });
```

here I assume your `posts` table have relationship `interaction`

Comment: Thanks. But this is filtering interactions. I want to filter posts based on interaction

Comment: @GopalGautam You may use same block using `whereHas()` before with, see updated answer